# Summing condition excludes rows without positive sum

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, group-by

I'm having a weird issue where in returning the sum of rows where a condition is true seems to only return rows *if* that condition is true - or at least, it is excluding a large majority of the rows that would otherwise be returned.

Original query - which returns all rows:

```
SELECT r.type, r.user1, r.user2, r.roomkey, r.name, r.active, m.active
FROM members as m 
INNER JOIN rooms as r ON m.roomid=r.id 
WHERE m.userid = ? 
ORDER BY r.active DESC, m.active DESC
```

For each row that was returned, I also wanted to get the number of records in another table with a newer timestamp than one of the timestamps I've already queried.

Modified query:

```
SELECT r.type, r.user1, r.user2, r.roomkey, r.name, r.active, m.active,
  COUNT(e.datetime > m.active) AS s 
FROM members as m 
INNER JOIN rooms as r ON m.roomid = r.id 
LEFT JOIN messages as e ON r.id = e.roomid 
WHERE m.userid = ? 
ORDER BY r.active DESC, m.active DESC
```

Basically, the original query returns all of the chat rooms a user is in. I want to modify the query to also return the number of unread messages corresponding to that room.

I'm trying to do it in a single query, so I don't have to execute another query in the while loop. Is there a better approach than the one above? I'm mainly worried about performance here, which is why I wanted to cram it all into a single query, but it doesn't seem to be working out. I've already confirmed that `HAVING` would not help me here and I had a similar lack of luck with subqueries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not valid (although MySQL might accept it), since you have an aggregation function in the `SELECT` clause but no `GROUP BY` clause. Also, the additional `JOIN` will evict rooms that have no messages, which, presumably, s not what you want.

You could use a `LEFT JOIN` and aggregate in the outer query, however I would recommend a correlated subquery instead:

```
SELECT 
    r.type, 
    r.user1, 
    r.user2, 
    r.roomkey, 
    r.name, 
    r.active,
    m.active,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM messages e 
        WHERE r.id = e.roomid AND e.datetime > m.active
    ) no_messages
FROM members as m 
INNER JOIN rooms as r ON m.roomid = r.id 
WHERE m.userid = ? 
ORDER BY r.active DESC, m.active DESC
```

For performance with this query, you want an index on `messages(room_id, datetime)`.

Comment: Is there supposed to be an `AS` before no_messages?

Comment: @InterLinked: actually the `AS` keyword is optional, you are free to add it if you find it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Using an extra join won't do what you expect, but will perform multiple unnecessary row matches.

You can use a scalar subquery:

```
SELECT r.type, r.user1, r.user2, r.roomkey, r.name, r.active, m.active,
  (
    select SUM(e.datetime > m.active) FROM messages e WHERE r.id = e.roomid 
  ) AS s 
FROM members as m 
INNER JOIN rooms as r ON m.roomid = r.id 
WHERE m.userid = ? 
ORDER BY r.active DESC, m.active DESC
```